# Is this a functional actor in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, concurrency, thread-safety, actor

I have been trying to find a means to control a program which ideally will allow for concurrency.  I eventually settled on actors being my best bet.  While vb.net has the TDF library, it specifically says it is for coarse grained operations.  Most of my operations are fairly fine-grained.  As such I eventually settled on the following code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Public Class LightActor

Private ReadOnly MessageQueue As New BlockingCollection(Of MessageBase)
Private Started As Boolean = False
Private Dirty As Boolean = False
Private RunningTask As Task

Public Sub Post(msg As MessageBase)
    MessageQueue.Add(msg)
End Sub

Public Sub StartProcessing()
    SyncLock MessageQueue
        If Not Started Then
            RunningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf Process)
            Started = True
        End If
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Private Sub Process()
    If MessageQueue.Count > 0 Then
        Dirty = True
        ProcessMessage(MessageQueue.Take)
    Else
        If Dirty Then
            Dirty = False
            ProcessEmpty()
        Else
            Dirty = True
            ProcessMessage(MessageQueue.Take)
        End If
    End If
    RunningTask = RunningTask.ContinueWith(AddressOf Process)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub ProcessEmpty()
    Console.WriteLine("empty")
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub ProcessMessage(msg As MessageBase)
    Console.WriteLine(msg.Signal.ToString)
End Sub

End Class
```

My question is this, as long as I am careful not to use shared variables and limit outside to communication to the Post method, is it safe to say that only one message will be processed at a time?

EDIT:  Also, can I make large numbers of these, or will they block all the threadpool threads?  If so, is there a way around that?

EDIT2: They block the threads, So I guess the question is how do I make this functional without blocking the threads.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I determined that the Dataflow library is much more lightweight than I though it was.  I can easily instantiate 100,000 actors and posting a message to each one, who in turn posts to another actor.  The 200,000 posts occurs in ~184 milliseconds on my machine.  That is sufficient for my purposes for the foreseeable future. I used to following three classes, in case someone else is looking for some fairly bare-boned actors (NotifyingObject is just a base class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
Public Class MessageBase

    Public ReadOnly Signal As eSignal

    Public Sub New(Signal As eSignal)
        Me.Signal = Signal
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Actor
    Inherits NotifyingObject

    Public Sub New()
        _MessageQueue = New ActionBlock(Of MessageBase)(AddressOf Process)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property MessageQueue As ITargetBlock(Of MessageBase)
        Get
            Return _MessageQueue
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected _MessageQueue As ActionBlock(Of MessageBase)

    Public ReadOnly Property isQueueEmpty As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._MessageQueue.InputCount = 0
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Post(message As MessageBase)
        _MessageQueue.Post(message)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Process(message As MessageBase)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ActsOnEmpty
    Inherits Actor

    Public Sub New()
        _MessageQueue = New ActionBlock(Of MessageBase)(AddressOf ProcessOnEmpty)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Process(message As MessageBase)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessOnEmpty(message As MessageBase)
        Process(message)
        If isQueueEmpty Then
            ProcessEmpty()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub ProcessEmpty()

    End Sub

End Class
```